# How do you handle relationships to other tables with PetaPoco?

Tags: petapoco

As an example, if I have a POCO for Forum and one for ForumPost, how can I elegantly return a list of ForumPosts and specify this right in the model.  I'm doing it manually now by adding my db.Query call directly in the List property, but is there a better way?

```
[TableName("Forum")]
[PrimaryKey("ForumID")]
[ExplicitColumns]
public class Forum : BaseModel
{
    [Column]
    public int ForumID { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string ForumName { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string ForumDescription { get; set; }
    [ResultColumn]
     public List<ForumPost> {
        get
```

{
   // return list of ForumPost - what's a good way to handle this?
}
}
     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an static extension to this, so I can set this in my property like this (using some of my classes).  This property would be in your POCO model:

```
 private List<AssessmentAssignment> _AssessmentAssignments;
    [ResultColumn]
    public List<AssessmentAssignment> AssessmentAssignments
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceExtensions<AssessmentAssignment>.GetRelatedList(this.GetType());
        }
        set
        {
            _AssessmentAssignments = value;
        }
    }
```

Here is the ServiveExtension that I wrote up to do it, but not sure i like this yet.  It works, but meh.  Anyone have any better ideas?

```
 public static class ServiceExtensions<T> where T : class, new()
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Experimental way to retrieve a foreign key related list with PetaPoco
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="PrimaryTableType"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<T> GetRelatedList(Type PrimaryTableType)
    {
        var primaryTableData = PocoData.ForType(PrimaryTableType);
        var relationshipTableData = PocoData.ForType(typeof(T));

        using (PetaPoco.Database db = new PetaPoco.Database("ConnStringName"))
        {
            PetaPoco.Sql sql = new PetaPoco.Sql("SELECT A.* FROM " + relationshipTableData.TableInfo.TableName + " A")
            .Append("JOIN " + primaryTableData.TableInfo.TableName + " B ON A." + primaryTableData.TableInfo.PrimaryKey + " = B." + primaryTableData.TableInfo.PrimaryKey);

            return db.Fetch<T>(sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see two issues with this, one being that the data is lazy loaded and the other being that depending on how many nested tables you have you could end up with a handful of separate queries being run that could have been satisfied with just one query.